# Allow user to switch accounts during a session

Tags: python, session, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a web app that I'm developing. User registers and logs in. Login requires username and password. The session starts with the username.

```
session['username'] = user.username
```

Currently the user only has one account per session. I want to allow the user to have multiple accounts per session. Example: Facebook allows you to have a personal page and public person page (or other type of page) under the same session. I am wanting something similar to that.

To do this, I am going to change the session to:

```
session['email'] = user.email
```

Assummming that username does not have a unique constraint in the database, this should allow me to switch between usernames in the same session.

Not having much experience with sessions, my questions are: Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a standard or better way to do this?

Comment: Reddit allows you to switch between accounts.  I have wondered how they managed that.  I updated to follow for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of what I provided above, the app was further developed. The login is similar to FB in the sense that you provide your email and password. There is a default user given on registration.

```
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email', '')
        password = request.form.get('password', '')
        dbsession = sessionmaker(bind=get_db())()
        error = None
        login = dbsession.query(Login).filter(Login.email == email).one_or_none()
        login_user, _ = dbsession.query(User, Login).\
            filter(
                User.email == Login.email,
                User.username == email
            ).one_or_none()
        print(login_user)
        if login is None or login_user is None:
            error = 'Username/Password Combination is invalid.'
        else:
            if login.check_password(password) is False:
                error = 'Username/Password Combination is invalid.'
                print(error)

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['email'] = login.email
            session['username'] = login_user.email
            session['userID'] = login_user.userID
            return redirect(url_for('base'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

After creating a new user, switching between them is done with the select user function, which is below.

```
@bp.route('/user/select', methods=('GET',))
def select_user():
    session_email = session.get('email', None)
    if session_email is not None:
        db = get_db()
        db_session = sessionmaker(bind=db)()

        results = db_session.query(User, Login).\
        filter(
            User.email == Login.email,
            Login.email == session_email
        ).all()
        users = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0].username, x[0]), results))
        requested_swap = request.args.get('user', None)
        if requested_swap is not None:
            if requested_swap in users:
                session['username'] = users[requested_swap].username
                session['userID'] = users[requested_swap].userID
        db_session.close()
        return render_template('auth/select_user.html', users=users)
    return render_template('auth/select_user.html')
```